# Como referenciar algum usuário de forma funcional?

Tags: suporte, notificações

Vejo frequentemente usuários se referenciando uns aos outros colocando o arroba antes do username desta forma: `@NomeUsuario`.
Até eu mesmo uso isso, mas por uma convenção.

Existe alguma funcionalidade por traz disso? Não deveria ao menos gerar um link para o perfil do usuário ou alerta-lo de alguma forma?

Como deixar isto mais útil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso serve para gerar uma notificação para alguém que você queira. Com isso você garante que esse alguém vai ler. É válido somente em comentários.

> **Respondendo aos comentários**
>
> O proprietário da publicação em que você estiver comentando ***sempre*** será notificado do seu comentário. Se você estiver respondendo a alguém que anteriormente comentou na mesma publicação, mencione o nome de usuário dele: `@peter` e `@PeterSmith` notificarão alguém que tenha feito comentários com o nome “Peter Smith”.
>
> Geralmente é suficiente mencionar apenas o primeiro nome do usuário cujo comentário você estiver respondendo, por ex. `@ben` ou `@marc`. No entanto, talvez deva ser mais específico se três pessoas chamadas Ben tiverem respondido em comentários anteriores, adicionando o primeiro caractere do sobrenome, por ex. `@benm` ou `@benc` Os espaços não são válidos nos nomes em respostas a comentários, portanto não use `@peter smith`, sempre use `@peters` ou `@petersmith`.
>
> Se o usuário ao qual você está respondendo não tem um nome e sobrenome natural, simplesmente insira caracteres suficientes do nome para deixar claro para quem você está respondendo. Três é o mínimo, portanto se você estiver respondendo para Fantástico, insira `@fan`, `@fant`, ou `@fantastic`.
>
> Você pode usar o mesmo método para notificar qualquer editor da publicação, ou – se for o caso – para o ♦ moderador que encerrou a pergunta.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Como chegar a essa informação? Clique em "adicionar comentário" aqui em baixo, depois clique em "ajuda", no canto direito. Por fim clique em "saiba mais", no fim as instruções.

Comment: Sim mas então isso é apenas uma cadeia de texto para referenciar usuários, não há nenhuma lógica por traz disso pelo que entendi. Os usuários serão notificados quando alguém comentar na mesma pergunta/resposta que ele comentou assim como os outros usuários que não foram mencionados. O `@` seria apenas uma convenção. Seria isso então?

Comment: @AnisanWesley Exato. Lembrando que você pode notificar apenas um usuário por comentário. E que isso não funciona em respostas e perguntas.

Comment: @AnisanWesley Se várias pessoas comentaram na mesma publicação, apenas serão notificados: 1) o autor da publicação; 2) o autor da pergunta, se a postagem comentada for uma resposta; 3) a primeira pessoa referida com o `@`; 4) uma ou duas pessoas que comentaram antes de você. Os outros comentadores **não** serão notificados.

Comment: Tem mais alguns detalhes, expliquei em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/943/como-funcionam-as-mencoes-e-notificacoes-com-usuario/1239#1239. @mgibsonbr No item (4), tem certeza do "uma ou duas"? Acho que é só uma, e que precisa ser o autor do post (pelo menos foi disso que achei referência).

Comment: @bfavaretto **Acho** que só é notificado automaticamente quando o autor da publicação comenta e apenas uma pessoa comentou antes nela. (Votando para fechar como duplicata)

Comment: @bfavaretto Estava com pressa pra sair enquanto escrevia o comentário, então não deu pra checar direito... Disse "uma ou duas" justamente porque não tinha certeza, mas me lembrava que tinha sim um lance da pessoa anterior ficar sabendo, mas posso estar enganado. Comentei porque - pelos comentários antes do meu - me deu a entender que o OP interpretou que *todo mundo* seria notificado independentemente de ter menção ou não. Daí a tentativa de esclarecimento.